# View polygon's index as non-tuple in Animation Nodes

Tags: faces, animation-nodes

I wonder how can I see *polygon's index* **not as tuple of vertices** indices, but **as single number**?
There is polygon viewer in `N-panel` which is what I want, but works only with unmodified geometry.

Comment: Unmodified geometry?

Comment: For example Cube with alembic cache of a Human will show indices of original Cube - this is how N-panel viewer works

Comment: So you want it with modifiers applied?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to have modifiers

Comment: Animation Nodes currently does not support this. Feel free to open an issue to github to suggest this option.